# Compress video with FFmpeg directly from mobile camera

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, video-compression, mobile-ffmpeg

Is there a way to record video in mobile and compress it with FFmpeg along the way, instead of recording it and only then using FFmpeg to compress it?

This solution would allow the device to record videos even when the available space in disk is low. I'm asking for both Android and iOS.

In https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg, there is a mention to a command meant to record video, but I can't seem to find any code example that implements it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ffmpeg supports several device capture methods including android_camera and avfoundation. See [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html).